# How to push validation message down?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, textbox

I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321745/WPF-Validation) tutorial and managed to get the validation message. The problem is that it overlays the element above. I know there is a workaround using margins, but I'wondering if it's possible to push the `TextBox` down (or shrink it) if there is an error message.

[image]

Comment: Sure. Make sure there is enough space between the "Message" label and your textbox for the validation error to fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Trigger on Validation.HasError to add the required top margin only if there is an error. This would basically make the TextBox shrink in order to make space for the error message.